# What is the difference between Scalability test and the other performance tests?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Are there any clear ideas that define the Scalability test? I have designed Load, Stress, Spike and Soak tests using JMeter Ultimate Thread Group but, i have not any idea about Scalability test differs from these tests. How to design a good scalability test with ultimate thread group in Jmeter for maximum user count is equal to 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Wikipedia article on Scalability testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing):

> Scalability testing, is the testing of a software application to measure its capability to scale up or scale out in terms of any of its non-functional capability.

So basically you can use the same approach as for the [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing), something like this:

[image]

then you need to pay attention to the following charts/KPIs:

- [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) - to show number of active virtual users
- [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond) - to show the system throughput
- [Charts of system resources consumption](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) - to show usage of CPU, RAM, etc.

Ideally the charts should be more or less the same/linear, i.e. if you increase the load by factor of 2x the throughput should increase by the same factor and resource consumption should increase proportionally.

If the charts are not equal/similar/proportional - then at some point the system won't be able to keep threads/transactions per second ratio and this will indicate the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)